# Upgrading to Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 while using ActiveGantt 2.6.0

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, gantt-chart

I would like to know if I will encounter any problems running `ActiveGanttVBN 2.6.0` on `Windows 7` using `Visual Studio 2010` and `VB.NET 4.0.`

My current configuration on which I am running `ActiveGantt 2.6.0` is `Windows XP`, `.NET 1.1`, and `Visual Studio 2003`.  I am upgrading to `Windows 7` and `.NET 4.0` and I need to know if I also need to upgrade to a newer version of `ActiveGantt`.

Answer (score 0):

.Net framework 1.1 does not run in Windows 7 64 bit, will you be using the 32 bit or 64 bit version of windows 7? Visual studio 2010 runs without any issue in Windows 7 and Windows 8, but I think it only supports .Net framework 2.0 and higher.

Comment: Now there are plenty of Virtualization tools out there, that way you can upgrade to Windows 7 and have .NET 1.1 Visual Studio 2003 and XP in a virtual environment.

Comment: My specific concern is about ActiveGantt. I am not sure whether ActiveGantt 2.6.0 will run on Windows 7 using .Net 4.0 and VS 2010.

Comment: You mean the runtime, it surely will (although I haven't tested it), Windows 7 runs Visual Basic 6 programs so it should not have a problem with NET 1.1.